# how to make icons <i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></i> display in template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add some icons to my project template. I think i am putting them in the right place but they are not displaying when i look at the template. I have even tried placing the icons in other places but it still doesn't display.

here is the place where the icons are on the template

```
<td>
    <i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></i>
    {{ equipment_order_item.quantity }}
    <i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></i>
</td>
```

Comment: Where have you included the FontAwesome CSS+font file?

Comment: i don't have a CSS file. do i need one?

Comment: The icons are part of a [project and library called FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/). They're not native to your browser, and has to be included explicitly (usually through a CSS file that includes the relevant webfonts).

Comment: But i am getting them from mdbootstrap. it just said i should copy and paste it where i want it